# Uncaught DOMException While executing in Edge and Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

My code is compatible with IE browser, while migrating to Edge below error occured.

**Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('<input type='button' value='175' name='DetailView1' style='font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: #000080; background-color: #E3DDCE; border: 0 solid #E3DDCE ' tabindex='1'  onfocus=javascript:strDelCode='175';gotFoucsOfView(Head0,'DetailView1'); onblur= javascript:onLostFoucsOfView(Head0); onclick=javascript:fnOPDetails('2895649','175','DetailView1'); >') is not a valid name.**

Sample Code:

```
        editval='DetailView'+btnCount;
        editvalue=strCustcode;
        row.id= "Head"+ count;
        var HeadID=row.id;
        
        if(strIpFlag == "Y"){
        ctrl="<input type='button' value='"+strCustcode+"' name='"+editval+"' style='font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: #000080; background-color: #ff9999; border: 0 solid #ff9999 ' tabindex='1'  onfocus=javascript:strDelCode='"+ editvalue +"';gotFoucsOfView("+HeadID+",'"+editval+"'); onblur= javascript:onLostFoucsOfView1("+HeadID+"); onclick=javascript:fnOPDetails1('"+ customeId +"','"+ editvalue +"','"+ editval+"'); >"
        }else{          
        ctrl="<input type='button' value='"+strCustcode+"' name='"+editval+"' style='font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: #000080; background-color: #E3DDCE; border: 0 solid #E3DDCE ' tabindex='1'  onfocus=javascript:strDelCode='"+ editvalue +"';gotFoucsOfView("+HeadID+",'"+editval+"'); onblur= javascript:onLostFoucsOfView("+HeadID+"); onclick=javascript:fnOPDetails('"+ customeId +"','"+ editvalue +"','"+ editval+"'); >"
        }
        td1.appendChild (document.createElement(ctrl));
```

could you please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) expects the first argument be a tag name, not a HTML string.

Comment: If you want to keep `ctrl` content as it is, the way to append it to the document is `td1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', ctrl);`.

Comment: `"compatible with IE browser"` you say! Wow- I'd be amazed if IE didn't throw it's toys completely out of the pram when trying to deal with this unusual javascript

Comment: The code is not compatible with IE either, "InvalidCharacterError" occurs.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you very much for your response td1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', ctrl); is working